# mongodb cakephp driver installation

Tags: cakephp, mongodb, installation

I'm trying to get mongodb to work with cakephp. I'm not sure on where to place ichikaway's mongodb driver for cakephp and where to add the database connection.

My directory structure is that, under `c:/websites/`, I have `cakephp` folder and my project `merry_flowers` folder.

i've already gone through ichikaway's github and mark story's website.

If I put the mongodb driver in \cakephp\app\plugins and database connection in \cakephp\app\config\database.php
I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal error 256: ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - Unable to import DataSource class mongodb.mongodbSource [CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 185]Code | Context
        if (!App::import('Datasource', $class, !is_null($conn['plugin']))) {
            trigger_error(sprintf(__('ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - Unable to import DataSource class %s', true), $class), E_USER_ERROR);$connName    =   "mongo"
$_this  =   ConnectionManager
ConnectionManager::$config = DATABASE_CONFIG object
ConnectionManager::$_dataSources = array
ConnectionManager::$_connectionsEnum = array
$conn   =   array(
    "plugin" => "mongodb",
    "classname" => "mongodbSource",
    "parent" => array(
    "filename" => "dbo_source",
    "classname" => "DboSource",
    "parent" => null,
    "plugin" => null
),
    "filename" => "dbo\mongodb_source"
)
$class  =   "mongodb.mongodbSource"ConnectionManager::loadDataSource() - CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 185
ConnectionManager::getDataSource() - CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 109
Model::setDataSource() - CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 2836
Model::__construct() - CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 469
ClassRegistry::init() - CORE\cake\libs\class_registry.php, line 142
Controller::loadModel() - CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 637
Controller::constructClasses() - CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 493
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 186
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 87
```

If I put the mongodb driver in \merry_flowers\plugins and add the database connection to \merry_flowers\config\database.php, I'm getting the following error:

```
  connecting to localhost:27017 failed: Unknown error APP\plugins\mongodb\models\datasources\mongodb_source.php, line 201
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which plugins folder you use.  Both have the same functionality.  Both are included for your organizational convenience.

Do you have a mysql database set up also?  If so, there might not be documentation for a dual installation.  If you only have one DB, you should be configuring it in `cakephp/app/config/database.php`

Comment: Yes, I already have a mysql database for merry_flowers project. So, ru saying that cakephp will work only with mysql OR mongodb and not both? But I need both of them for my project. Mysql for structured data and mongodb for reporting purpose. Earlier when i had posted a question on this, I was told that it is possible for both to work fine together. Thank you.

Comment: I've given up trying to get mongodb to work with cakephp. Instead, I realized that i can store that data (for reporting purpose) in mysql. So, now I can query it to produce the report. As, therealomrose said, there is no documentation on the net to get both mysql and mongodb  to work with cakephp.